# Test Case for Each Unit Test?

Tags: unit-tests, documentation

It seems highly impractical to have a test case/ticket for every unit test; however, the only experiences I have to draw from are from college, and an internship -both of which stressed having each unit test associated with a ticket.  This seems especially time consuming when it comes to combination testing.

Is this an industry standard or expectation?

Comment: What do you call a "ticket"?

Comment: Sorry: Like a Jira ticket, or Bugzilla ticket.

Comment: OK, what is it? A problem/bug/etc in the software? If yes, then why should be every test associated with such a ticket? If the test is PASSED then there is no ticket for it. And if the software have no bug (let's imagine an almost impossible thing) then there are no tickets at all.

Comment: It was software that lacked tests; I was tasked to achieve a degree of coverage.  They wanted a test case for every unit test for documentation purposes.

Comment: We tried using Jira items to track our higher-level tests and it was a nightmare to keep in sync--I can't imagine having to do that for each unit test. A big advantage of unit tests is that they're relatively cheap compared to other, larger tests. If you introduce a heavy documentation burden for each unit test, you lose that advantage.

Comment: @user29084 are you saying they want a ticket for each and every existing test, or that they want a ticket for each new test that needs to be written?  The latter isn't crazy if you're doing an inventory of missing tests.  If they're expecting a sub-task to each ticket that enumerates out each unit test for new features, that's bonkers.

Comment: @ernie It was more the latter.  I just felt it was very time consuming with little benefit to create a unit test ticket for every unit test I made.  Especially if I have several unit tests that differed only in input, but not concept.

Comment: @user29084 If your unit tests can be grouped e.g. several tests cover the same functionality but with different inputs and expected outputs, consider adding one ticket for the group of tests and document the different range cases in the ticket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the comments, you mention that you were doing an inventory of missing tests, and that they wanted tickets for tests you were adding.

This sounds pretty reasonable, as long as they're not expecting a ticket for each and every test.  Using a four-function calculator as an example, I could definitely see tickets of the form "Add unit test coverage for multiplying negatives and positive values" that might encompass several unit tests (or the combination testing you mention).

If they're expecting tickets like "Add unit test coverage for a negative times a positive" and "Add unit test cover for a negative times a negation", etc, then that's crazy.

In other words, I can see value in tracking the work being done (or what unit tests still need writing), but not in spelling out each and every test case.

Comment: Would there be circumstances in an industry that'd require that kind of detail? I'm sorry for having to ask because I can't find much information about the.. methodology / documentation side of testing.  I can find dozens of sources on how to write a good unit test.

Comment: Sure, highly regulated industries (e.g. medical devices) could have that level of detail.

Comment: They could, it doesn't mean they have....

Answer (score 2):

```
Is this an industry standard or expectation?
```

**No** and hopefully it will never be. Hopefully [TDD](http://www.jamesshore.com/Agile-Book/test_driven_development.html) will be. People who think you can document in a workflow-tracker when and how to create unit-tests really miss the point.

Answer (score 1):

well, this question is very wide. I can tell you that I've seen two approaches:

**1.** developers should do the unit tests in the same ticket of the feature that they are developing - and the unit test goes in the same commit of the features. (I've to say that this approach is the usual that I know and also I think it's more efficient).

**2.** the second is divide the tickets into classes or modules of the system. I've seen this approach in huge systems that the unit testing wasn't a practice at the initial phase of the product.

Thus, I think the first scenario is the one I like more and I have seen more.

Comment: I agree it's a bit open ended due to lack of specifics. I have no issue implementing unit tests for a wide variety of cases; however, providing documention for all of them is something I have difficulty accepting as I don't see the benefit to it. I can understand documenting the concept being tested and how, but not for each iteration of test for that one concept.

Comment: @user29084 I agree with you. I also think that the best documentation for unit tests is the [convention name](https://dzone.com/articles/7-popular-unit-test-naming) that better fits for you and of course for the project.